# Is $\limsup A_n=\inf_N\sup_{n\ge N} A_n$ for set?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Is $\limsup A_n=\inf_N\sup_{n\ge N} A_n$ where $A_n\subset X$ and limsup is set-theoretic limit.

I know it holds for real numbers. Just wondering if the same holds for sets.

Comment: How do you define $\sup$ for arbitrary sets?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas see http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/A_4.html. But I think I understand it now. It should hold.